# Android touch identical coordinate bug (on Unity 4.5 engine)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I’ve been experiencing a wierd bug around touch handling in android devices.
I’m developingr a quite simple cross-platform mobile game in Unity 4.5, with only two kind of input: touch swipe up and down.
The bug is that on rare occasions the two Touch event I recieve, phase Began and Ended(/Canceled) has exactly the same X and Y coordinates, even at some pretty big swipe. I’ve tried to debug my code, checking all the related values at a lot of points, and it really seems that the wrong data cames directly from the touch event.
As I said, coordinates are identical, phase is as expected (first it’s Began, and finaly its Ended), and there’s a 60ms gap between the events.

There’s a suspicious Error before the events. I tend to suspect it’s the source of my bug, but searching for it in any forums hasn’t got me any solution (the main reply was „ignore it”).

Could you please advise me if it could be the real source (and if so, what can I do with it), or do you have any idea where yould this come from?

Thank you very much!

The suspicious error message:

> channel ’4149ad80 com.[MyCompany].[MyApp]/com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (client)’ ~ Failed to receive dispatch signal. status=-11

The basick setup of my touch handler (C#):

```
if (Input.touchCount >= 1)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began && !touched)
            {
                firstTouch = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
                touched = true;
            }   
            else if (touched &&
                                    (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended
                                    || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Canceled))
            {
                Vector3 lastTouch = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            }
                else if (lastTouch.y - firstTouch.y >= touchDeadZoneSize)
                {
                    Up();
                    touched = false;
                }
                else if (firstTouch.y - lastTouch.y >= touchDeadZoneSize)
                {
                    Down();
                    touched = false;
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `Input.GetTouch(0).position;` return a `Vector2` not a `Vector3`.

And I think it is better to use `Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition;` to get the distance of the swipe..

e.g

```
if(Input.GetTouch(0).deltaPosition >= touchDeadZoneSize){
  Up();
  touched = false;
}else{
  Down();
  touched = false;
}
```